move Null Values to the end
how can i move Null Values to the end Regardless of the Sorting Direction using v-data-table and vuetify3.
Above i have attached a reproducable example, i want to the null values apears at the end of the sorting:
Thanks is advance!
Vuetify Playground

What you need to return is undefined to put null/undefined values at the end of the sort regardless of direction.
customKeySort: {
  value: (d1, d2) => {
    // Check for null/undefined values and sort them to the end
    if (!d1 && !d2) return undefined
    if (!d1) return undefined
    if (!d2) return undefined
    if (d1 > d2) return 1
    if (d2 > d1) return -1

    return 0
  },
},

updated Vuetify playground
